# How to Build hybrid app using salesforce sdk

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, phonegap, hybrid

How to start developing hybrid app from the scratch?I read lot of blogs regarding this but none of the blog provided the right solution....I tried phone gap but the apk hich was delivered using phonegap doesn't perform any operation it acts just like an image..Can anyone guide me in this processs...

Comment: Manoj, this is a bit vague. Can you please add some information on exactly where you got stuck and why you say it just 'acts like an image'? There's a good guide to creating a hybrid app on developer.force.com

Comment: I uploaded the zip file to phonegap which consists of config,build,js and css files...for the app but the apk file which was delivered by phonegap doesnt perform any action just diplayed index.html file...FYI i tried Contact Explorer app

Comment: This site describes the steps required after you upload the zip file:  http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_phonegap-build_index.md.html#Introducing%20PhoneGap%20Build